# Is this shirk please answer

Tags: sin, shirk

Assalamualaikum last day my brother slip from the bed and my mother catched him so at that time I told it is allah who had saved him from being getting hurt is it shirk here I don't intend to compare mother and allah or I dont intend to commit shirk or beleive in that comparison I told it because allah is the one who help us when we are

Comment: In fact saying your mother saved him is considered as shirk. As your mother is only the cause or tool for his saving.

Comment: I didn't said my mother saved him

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be Shirk, since you believe that it is Allah who had saved him. And you didn't associate anyone or anything with Allah.
Next time, to (hopefully) reduce your waswas, say "Alhamdulillah" which means "praise be to Allah". Since it's the same thing.

And Allah knows best.